# Translation of Haken's paper "Theorie der Normalflächen"

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, translation, computational-topology

Haken's paper "Theorie der Normalflächen" is one of the formative papers in the development of normal surface theory and provides an algorithm for detecting the unknot.

While there are now a variety of great introductions to the topic of normal surface theory, improvements to Haken's algorithm (in terms of computational time), and a detailed MathSciNet review of this paper due to D. B. A. Epstein, I was wondering if a translation of "Theorie der Normalflächen" exists.

Comment: As far as I know, no translations are available.  Reading those old papers of Haken, Schubert and Dehn I mostly get stuck on the *old* PL terminology they use.  A solid torus is a vollringe, etc.

Comment: Translations of those papers would be useful though.  Many of those old topology papers are rather dense with ideas.  Because of the jargon on top of language differences, few people read them anymore.  Which is a shame because there are some ideas in those old papers that haven't been written up in any other format.

Comment: Much of Haken's work was redone, check Hemion's book (although he works with triangulations) and Matveev's book (he, as Haken, works with normal surfaces with respect to handle decompositions). Maybe these sources will suffice for your purposes.

Comment: What is the actual problem with the German version? If the paper isn't too long and it the main problem is the language per se, it shouldn't be too hard to translate it. Maybe some Rosetta stone project should be initiated, in which people volunteer to aid in translating important mathematical papers or help in clarifying the meaning of words or sentences of an unfamiliar language.

Comment: @Misha - I have finally gotten around to reading Hemion's book.  While "inspiring", it is much too vague and much too error-ridden to serve as a primary reference on normal surface theory.